# Ввод входных данных со стороннего ресурса

Tags: javascript, node.js

На сайте с задачами выбрал язык JavaScript. Подскажите, как данные из поля "Test input" записать в первые 3 переменные. Возможно, необходимо использовать process.stdin, process.stdout, но я не знаю, как именно.

[image: Test input - поле, в которое нужно вводить]

Код на изображении, возможно пригодится:

```js
let n_count = 1;
let e_energy = 5;
let n_energy = 8;
for (var e_count = 1; ;e_count++){
    if (e_count*e_energy >= n_count*n_energy) {
        break;
    }
}
console.log(e_count);
```

Comment: А что за *сайт с задачами*?

Comment: https://nodejs.org/api/readline.html